# How to reinstall Windows 8

Tags: windows, uefi

I installed Ubuntu removing windows. I now want to reinstall Windows 8, so I have downloaded a Windows 8 iso. My laptop is Asus and has UEFI, so how can I reinstall Windows? It does not bootswith the boot-able flash drive, please help me!

Comment: This site is about Ubuntu, not Windows. You can ask SuperUser.com, which is more general than AskUbuntu.com.

Comment: You would also probably get a better answer at http://superuser.com/, you can also use the same StackExchange account.

Comment: Are you trying to prove something by asking a windows-related question on an ubuntu forum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a bootable usb drive using [unetbootin](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/&ei=-drrUpPbJYLcyQHVlIGYBA&usg=AFQjCNFG2iJy14ueI6PKA0HBkn1cP-KoBg&sig2=tAtu-NYYRawme-OIA5H-vA&bvm=bv.60444564,d.aWc) to create a windows installtion usb.
After making it bootable restart your computer and enter the boot options menu and then in the boot options menu select the usb drive starting with **UEFI**, Now save your settings and restart your system where you will be guided by the windows installation part and Install your fresh windows.